# Travelling from Ireland to England on an Australian passport as a British Citizen

Tags: passports, ireland, australian-citizens, england

I’m planning to travel to Ireland for a few days from England, but my English passport has expired. However, I have a valid Australian passport which I can use to enter Ireland, but I’m worried about the journey back. If I fly from Ireland to England on an Australian passport, can I show my expired English passport as proof of citizenship so I don’t need a visa? (As stated on the travel website). Unfortunately RyanAir only accepts a valid passport as identification, hence why I require a valid passport to fly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably not encounter any border control at your return to the UK, since both are part of the Common Travel Area

> can I show my expired English passport as proof of citizenship so I don’t need a visa

Even if you encounter border control for some reason (sometimes on ferries for ex.), it's a good thing to have, but your aus passport is perfectly acceptable and would get you in without issue since you don't need a visa to enter on it

Comment: But will Ryanair accept these documents?

Comment: @phoog I don't see why not, as Australian citizens don't need a visa to enter the UK or Ireland...

Comment: I'm a British citizen but I've flown to and entered Britain on my Canadian passport countless times.